# Linker error for geometry_msgs

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I explore ros2 recently. Differences with ros, creating custom messages, pub sub examples for c++ etc.

I just wanted to demonstrate that another package can be used in a custom message.

I generated a message for simple pub-sub example.
Message and its CMakefile in autodrive_msgs package :

AccelCommand.msg

```
float32 accel
geometry_msgs/Vector3 v
```

CMakefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(autodrive_msgs)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp)
find_package(autodrive_msgs)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/AccelCommand.msg"
 )
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

I can generate the message. However It gives me a linker error when I want to use the message.
Codes and CMakefile in pub_sub package:

pub.cpp:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "autodrive_msgs/msg/accel_command.hpp"     // CHANGE

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalPublisher()
  : Node("minimal_publisher"), count_(0)
  {
    publisher_ = this->create_publisher<autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand>("topic", 10);    // CHANGE
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
      500ms, std::bind(&MinimalPublisher::timer_callback, this));
  }

private:
  void timer_callback()
  {
    auto message = autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand();                               // CHANGE
    message.accel = this->count_++;                                        // CHANGE
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%d'", message.accel);    // CHANGE
    publisher_->publish(message);
  }
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  rclcpp::Publisher<autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand>::SharedPtr publisher_;         // CHANGE
  size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalPublisher>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

sub.cpp:

```
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "autodrive_msgs/msg/accel_command.hpp"     // CHANGE
using std::placeholders::_1;

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalSubscriber()
  : Node("minimal_subscriber")
  { 
    subscription_ = this->create_subscription<autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand>(          // CHANGE
      "topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
  }

private:
  void topic_callback(const autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand::SharedPtr msg) const       // CHANGE
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%d'", msg->accel);              // CHANGE
  }
  rclcpp::Subscription<autodrive_msgs::msg::AccelCommand>::SharedPtr subscription_;       // CHANGE
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

CMakefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(pub_sub)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp)
find_package(autodrive_msgs)
find_package(geometry_msgs)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)


add_executable(talker src/pub.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp autodrive_msgs geometry_msgs)         # CHANGE

add_executable(listener src/sub.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(listener rclcpp autodrive_msgs geometry_msgs)     # CHANGE

install(TARGETS
  talker
  listener
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

I get this error message:

```
clepz@clepz-PC:~/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2$ colcon build  --packages-select pub_sub
Starting >>> pub_sub 
--- stderr: pub_sub                              
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::get_serialized_size(geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > const&, unsigned long)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::max_serialized_size_Vector3(bool&, unsigned long)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_deserialize(eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&, geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_serialize(geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > const&, eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [talker] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::get_serialized_size(geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > const&, unsigned long)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::max_serialized_size_Vector3(bool&, unsigned long)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_deserialize(eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&, geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined reference to `geometry_msgs::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_serialize(geometry_msgs::msg::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> > const&, eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [listener] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< pub_sub [2.17s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [2.29s]
  1 package failed: pub_sub
  1 package had stderr output: pub_sub
```

If I delete geometry_msgs/vector v and its dependency from cmakefile, pub and sub examples are running.

I tried many things such as building without colcon, I gave all libraries with manual. Result is the same undefined reference to gemometry_msgs.
I tried to build in ros2 docker with same packages. Result is the same.

I can get that from same terminal where i tried to build:

```
clepz@clepz-PC:~/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2$ ros2 msg show geometry_msgs/msg/Vector3
# This represents a vector in free space.

float64 x
float64 y
float64 z
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375409/linker-error-for-geometry_msgs/) by [clepz](https://answers.ros.org/users/46448/clepz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I copied your code to give it a try and it did compile for me. I however then get the following error when trying to run a node:

```
$ ros2 run pubsub talker 
/home/sander/install/pubsub/lib/pubsub/talker: symbol lookup error: /home/sander/install/autodrive_msgs/lib/libautodrive_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13geometry_msgs3msg24typesupport_fastrtps_cpp27max_serialized_size_Vector3ERbm
```

I could get it working with the following pointers:

- Have you sourced the whole of the ROS 2 environment? If perhaps you only do `source install/local_setup.bash`, only packages in your local workspace will be available, but not the base ROS 2 packages. So `autodrive_msgs` can be found, but `geometry_msgs` not, which looks like what you get. If this is the case, you need to either `source install/setup.bash`, or source the base environment first. See also: https://answers.ros.org/question/292566/what-is-the-difference-between-local_setupbash-and-setupbash/
- Your `autodrive_msgs` package is the one with the direct dependency on `geometry_msgs`, so you should specify that in that package. I am slightly surprised the `autodrive_msgs` package built without doing so and thought that that was your issue, but I guess the generation process doesn't actually need to work with the base messages. You should still specify the dependency though to enable easier use of your msgs package. For this, you should add this to `auodrive_msgs/CMakeLists.txt`:

  ```
    find_package(geometry_msgs)
  ```

  And then specify the dependency in the `rosidl_generate_interface` call:

  ```
    rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
      "msg/AccelCommand.msg"
      DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs
     )
  ```

  Finally you should also have a `<depend>geometry_msgs</depend>` in `autodrive_msgs/package.xml`. This way any package that depends on your `autodrive_msgs` package will know it transitively depends on `geometry_msgs` and you don't have specify that in `puch_sub/CMakeLists.txt`
- You have `find_package(autodrive_msgs)` in `autodrive_msgs/CMakeLists.txt`, implying the package depends on itself, which can't be (you should get a warning about that when building the package), so that line can/should go.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clepz](https://answers.ros.org/users/46448/clepz/) on 2021-04-05**:
Thank you a lot. It builds now. I get this warning:

WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.ament:The path '/home/clepz/workspace/autodrivemessages_ros2/install/pub_sub' in the environment variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist

Should I ignore that?

**Comment by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) on 2021-04-05**:
Good to hear you got it building! The warning you get usually indicates you removed a previously built package from the `install` directory or maybe renamed and rebuilt the package, after you had sourced `[local_]setup.bash`, causing the old path still to be in the `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable even though it is not there on disk any more. You can indeed ignore it. Opening a new terminal and sourcing the workspace again may resolve it, or else a completely fresh start by doing `rm -r install build` and build again. In general it is advisable not to source `install/[local_]setup.bash` in the same terminal where you run Colcon (but to just source the base ROS 2 installation), to prevent this kind of issue and hidden issues with how dependencies are specified in your packages.